# Can't get my delay function to work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a card flip in CSS and jQuery. The situation I'm using it in, the front side needs to be in an overflow hidden container and when it flips it needs to be in an overflow visible container.

Here's my example:

```
$('.front').click(function(){
    $('#card').toggleClass('flipped');
    $('.container').toggleClass('flippedContainer');
});
$('.back').click(function(){
    $('#card').toggleClass('flipped');
    $('.container').delay(500).toggleClass('flippedContainer');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ANfuL/

As you notice going from front to back works fine but I need the class toggle to wait a half second before toggling. I tried delay but it doesn't seem to do anything.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delay` only works by default with the effects queue.
Try using `setTimeout` instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){$('.container').toggleClass('flippedContainer');},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code to use javascript's setTimeout method.  You can see the update here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/fT8KJ/

```
$('.front').click(function(){
        $('#card').toggleClass('flipped');
        $('.container').toggleClass('flippedContainer');
    });
    $('.back').click(function(){
        //waits half second
        setTimeout(function(){
           $('#card').toggleClass('flipped');
           $('.container').delay(500).toggleClass('flippedContainer');
        },500);


        //$('#card').toggleClass('flipped');
        //$('.container').delay(500).toggleClass('flippedContainer');
    })
```

I basically changed your ".back" click event handler by adding setTimeout.  In setTimeout, I created a function that implemented your original .back code and specified the time needed to elapse before it fired off.

Answer (score 0):

`delay` can only be used for animation effects in the jQuery queue.

You need to use `setTimeout();`

http://jsfiddle.net/ANfuL/5/

Answer (score 0):

The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native `setTimeout` function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

```
$('.back').click(function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
       $('#card').toggleClass('flipped');
       $('.container').delay(500).toggleClass('flippedContainer');
    },500);
 })
```

DEMO`-->` http://jsfiddle.net/ANfuL/7/